# Pass integer between two view controllers

Tags: xcode5

What I'm trying to accomplish is pretty simple: passing an integer between view controllers. I've looked at a ton of tutorials and I thought I had it, but my code seems to need fixing.

ViewController1.h

```
int SelectNumber;

@interface ViewControllerIncome : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *inputNumber;
}

-(void)setIntVal:(NSUInteger)inVal;
```

ViewController1.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

-(void)setIntVal:(NSUInteger)inVal
{
_intVal = inVal;
}

- (IBAction)enterButton:(id)sender{

SelectNumber = _intVal;

}
```

ViewController2.h

```
int incomeNumber;

NSUInteger _intVal;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *NumberLabel;
```

ViewController2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_intVal];
incomeNumber = incomeNumber + _intVal;

NumberLabel.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", incomeNumber];
_intVal = 0;


}
```

As you can see, the goal is to take the integer `SelectNumber`, pass it to the other view controller and add it to `inputNumber`, and display it with the label `NumberLabel`.

Comment: you haven't asked a question.  Maybe this would be better for CodeReview

Answer (score 0):

ViewController1 needs a reference to ViewController2. The you can set a Property of ViewController2.

Your code looks a little confusing. What exactly are you planning to do? Are both ViewControllers visible at the same time or are you planning to pass the value during navigation from the one to the other?

Comment: i thought #import ViewController2.h would suffice, but i guess not

Comment: I'm trying to have a view controller where the user selects a number , which is the integer **SelectNumber**. I want to pass that integer to the other view controller where I can display it on a label **NumberLabel**

Comment: All i've found online are tutorials for passing text, image, etc.... but not just an integer. Thank you for any help

Comment: No, the import is not enough. How are you creating your ViewController2 class? Inside ViewController1?

Comment: I must be missing something. I just use one created by default and then create one by dragging on a new view controller, then creating a new file which creates the new .h and .m files. then under the identity inspector I declare the class name in the Class field to link the new files with the new view controller. in addition i have a button setup as a modal link to the second view controller. what am i missing?